# R grouped for loop seq_along length - 1?

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, dplyr, iteration

I'm trying to create an indicator for number of "tries" it takes to get a project accepted. I think a for loop is the way to go, but I don't have a ton of loop experience in R, and the logic is kind of complicated. Any help/advice/feedback would be greatly appreciated!

In the toy example, "accept" is "C" and the switch to iterate "try" forward is if submission (A) is reset (B) or a submission (A) is accepted (C).

Within a group, if the event order is A > B or A > C, then iterate "try" forward by 1. Otherwise, the "try" count should remain the same. Obviously, the "real" example is much more complicated than this toy example.

Currently, I'm just trying to get the try count correct, without worrying about grouping.

I'm not sure how to limit seq_along to stop at, essentially, [group_by %>% length(group) - 1]. Is there a better alternative?

```
df = data.frame(group = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2), 
                 event = c("A","B","A","A","C","A","B","A","C"))

df$try <- 0
for (i in seq_along(df$event)){
    if (df$event[[i]] == "A" &  
          df$event[[i+1]] %in% c("B", "C"))
      {
        df$try[[i]] <- df$try + 1
    } else {
        df$try[[i]] <- df$try
    }
}

# this essentially shows the correct answer (win = try + 1, loss = try), 
# but has "df$event[[i + 1]] : subscript out of bounds", 
# and I need to save the outcome so I can access later

df$try <- 0
for (i in seq_along(df$event)){
    if (df$event[[i]] == "A" &  
          df$event[[i+1]] %in% c("B", "C"))
      {
        print("Win")
    } else {
        print("Loss")
    }
}
```

My expected (final) answer for the toy example would be: try = c(1,1,1,2,2,1,1,2,2); each group 1 and 2 take 2 "tries" to be accepted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `lead` to get next value in `dplyr`. Try this -

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(result = cumsum(event == 'A' & lead(event) %in% c('B', 'C'))) %>%
  ungroup

#  group event   try result
#  <dbl> <chr> <dbl>  <int>
#1     1 A         1      1
#2     1 B         1      1
#3     1 A         1      1
#4     1 A         2      2
#5     1 C         2      2
#6     2 A         1      1
#7     2 B         1      1
#8     2 A         2      2
#9     2 C         2      2
```

Kept the `try` column in the output for comparison purpose.

Comment: Thanks! This is very nice, and appears quicker than the loop (not actually tested).
I used ```max(cumsum ...) ``` to get the final result for each group. 
I think dplyr::lead will be very useful for this project; I haven't seen it before!

Answer (score 0):

You can solve the "subscript out of bound" issue by adding one more if.

```
if(i+1 > nrow(df){
print('do nothing')
} else if (
#followed by your original code
)
```

I assume that if the last row, the value will just be 0. So another if should do this trick.

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame(group = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2), 
                event = c("A","B","A","A","C","A","B","A","C"))


temp <- data.frame(NULL)
for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
  if(i+1 > nrow(df)){
    print('This is the last row')
    temp <- rbind(temp, 0)
  } else if(df$event[[i]] == 'A' &
     df$event[[i+1]] %in% c('B', 'C'))
  {
    temp <- rbind(temp, 1)
  } else {
    temp <- rbind(temp, 0)
  }
}

df2 <- cbind(df, temp) %>%
  mutate(
    cumulative_sum = cumsum(X1)
  )
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for this additional idea! I'm not sure how it will work with a group_by, though. My expected (final) answer for the toy example would be: X1 = c(1,1,1,2,2,1,1,2,2)

Comment: It seems like we have 2 issues at hand:

1.) Group_by
I believe you are not sure if you can solve the "Subscript out of bound" issue if you use it in your real work which will also involve group_by(). Am I correct?

2.) Result
Although my code can solve the "subscript out of bound issue," the expected answer is not what you want. 

Do I correctly understand the situation?

Comment: 1. I planned to explore "group_modify" and "group_map", but correct: I do not have an exact idea for solving the iteration by groups.
Ex: use the for loop as the function argument in group_modify
```iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  group_modify(~ {
     quantile(.x$Petal.Length, probs = c(0.25, 0.5, 0.75)) %>%
     tibble::enframe(name = "prob", value = "quantile")
  })```
2. The answer is close to what I want, but I'd like to use as few steps and extra dataframes as possible since this is a very large dataset

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for now:

Added a "break" if i + 1 would exceed the length

```
df$try <- 0
for (i in seq_along(df$event)){
    if (i+1 == length(df$event)){
      break
      } else if (df$event[[i]] == "A" &  
          df$event[[i+1]] %in% c("B", "C"))
      {
        print("Win")
    } else (
        print("Loss")
    )
}

# updated toy df to show N tries differs:

df = data.frame(group = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2), 
                 event = c("A","B","A","A","B","A","C","A","B","A","C"))

df$try <- 0
for (i in seq_along(df$event)){
    if (i == length(df$event)){ # use i otherwise it doesn't catch the last switch
      break
      } else if (df$event[[i]] == "A" &  
          df$event[[i+1]] %in% c("B", "C"))
      {
        df$try[[i]] <- + 1
    } else (
        df$try[[i]]
    )
}

df %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  mutate(N_tries = max(cumsum(try)))
```